# PHP error : count() throws Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php

I am getting this error

> count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

**CODE**

```
if(count($settings['cols'])>0)
{
    $settings_list[] = 'cols:[' . self::prepare_reports_settings_val($settings['cols']) . ']';
}
```

I am getting error in `if(count($settings['cols'])>0)`. What should I write instead of count here?

**UPDATE**
all of the three answer are correct . is_array() worked and if($settings['cols']) also worked . I can't mark right all three . So I am writing here . Thank you all :-)

Comment: What exactly is the $settings['cols'], can we see a bit more of the code?

Comment: Based on what little you said you could be looking for the `sizeOf()` method which gives you the number of entries present in the position `['cols']` of the array `$settings`
`if(sizeOf($settings['cols'])>0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(is_array($settings['cols']) && count($settings['cols'])>0)
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably don't need to count it, as `$settings['cols']` is already the number you want to compare. Just compare it directly:

```
if ($settings['cols'] > 0) {
```

Comment: ok . I will try this way

Answer (score 1):

as you say count use for array and object .
first of all you should know what is the type of your variable.
so you can use

echo gettype($settings['cols']);

and see what type you have.

i think  $settings['cols'] is a number that you need .
you can use echo or var_dump to see it.

but if you want to get count of what you have you should do this:

1.arrays and objects : count()
2.for string : strlen()
3.for int : i think you dont need it